# Using Laravel's Queue for sending messages

Tags: php, laravel, queue, message

I want to send messages by email or SMS or push notification and I want to use Laravel's queue.

Suppose I have more than 10000 email that I want to send via queue. This line starts the queue push:

```
Queue::push('SendEmail', array('email' =>'me@email.com'));
```

Now I do not know what this queue exactly does with ironMQ,means when my messages start to send after pushing and what's benefit of ironMQ?
Is there any help or ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The external service is just the manager, use Queue::later() if you want to defer the job.